# ssh-agent error "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I need to add a public key to `ssh-agent` but I'm getting the following error

> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

I'm using Windows 7. I found that agent is running. But `ssh-add` is useless as it gives an error above.

Comment: See also [Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17846529/456814).